# How to call aes_encrypt (and other Spark SQL functions) in a pyspark DataFrame context

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I need to call the new Spark function [aes_encrypt](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/functions/aes_encrypt.html) in a DataFrame context.

The function can be called in a SQL context like this:

```sql
SELECT *, aes_encrypt(col1, key, 'GCM') AS col1_encrypted FROM myTable
```

or like this:

```py
df = sql("SELECT *, aes_encrypt(col1, key, 'GCM') AS col1_encrypted FROM myTable")
```

Is there any other way to call it in a DataFrame context, something like this?

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import aes_encrypt

df = table("myTable").withColumn("col1_encrypted", aes_encrypt("col1", key, 'GCM')
```

(I know it can't be imported since it **doesn't** exist in pyspark, this is just an example of other Spark functions that can be called)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `expr` function ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.expr.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr)) for that - just pass corresponding SQL expression:

```py
df = table("myTable") \
  .withColumn("col1_encrypted", expr("aes_encrypt(col1, key, 'GCM')"))
```

Another alternative is `selectExpr` ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr)):

```
df = table("myTable") \
  .selectExpr("*", "aes_encrypt(col1, key, 'GCM') as col1_encrypted")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [(
    "João",25,"Masculino",
), (
    "Maria",20,"Feminino",
), (
    "Pedro",30,"Masculino",
)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=["nome", "idade", "sexo"])

df.show()

encryption_key = 'key'

jujuba = df.withColumn(
    'teste_encryption', expr(f"base64(aes_encrypt(nome, '{encryption_key}', 'ECB'))")
).withColumn(
    'teste_descryption', expr(f"aes_decrypt(unbase64(teste_encryption), '{encryption_key}', 'ECB')").cast(StringType())
)
```